# Multi-label classification Keras metrics

Tags: machine-learning, keras, classification, multilabel-classification

Which metrics is better for multi-label classification in Keras: `accuracy` or `categorical_accuracy`? Obviously the last activation function is `sigmoid` and as loss function is `binary_crossentropy` in this case.

Comment: I don't think that 'categorical_crossentropy' is right for multi label classification.

Comment: how many classes are you talking about ?

Comment: There are 18 labels, not classes, in the sense that every image has multi labels

Comment: Please, Never use categorical_accuracy for multi-label classification, it instead gives you the precision

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not use Accuracy for classification tasks with unbalanced classes.
Especially for multi-label tasks, you probably have most of your labels to be False. That is, each data point can only have a small set of labels compared to the cardinality of all of the possibile labels.
For that reason accuracy is not a good metric, if your model predict all False (sigmoid activation output < 0.5) then you would measure a very high accuracy.

I would analyze either the AUC or recall/precision at each epoch.
Alternatively a multi-label task can be seen as a ranking task (like Recommender Systems) and you could evaluate precision@k or recall@k where k are the top predicted labels.

If your Keras back-end is TensorFlow, check out the full list of supported metrics here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, there is no metric named `accuracy` in Keras. When you set `metrics=['accuray']` in Keras, the correct accuracy metric will be inferred automatically based on the loss function used. As a result, since you have used `binary_crossentropy` as the loss function, the `binary_accuracy` will be chosen as the metric.

Now, you should definitely choose `binary_accuracy` over `categorical_accuracy` in a multi-label classification task since classes are independent from each other and the prediction for each class should be considered independently of the predictions for other classes.

Comment: I don't think `binary_accuracy` is very good since it can give you a false sense of accomplishment. Since most of the labels will be zero, if your model predicts mostly zeros then you can easily get 95+% on `binary_accuracy`

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya That's a good point to consider when interpreting the result of `binary_accuracy` especially when the number of labels is high. However, in any case, in a multi-label classification task `categorical_accuracy` is not a valid choice.

Comment: this is **not** multi-class question. see the OP comments

Comment: @BoppityBop I think I was aware of that as I have clearly mentioned this in my answer.

Comment: that what I read:.. in a multi-label classification task since classes are independent from each other and the prediction for each class.. am I missing something?

Comment: @BoppityBop Well, pardon me but I don't understand what is confusing you? I have clearly stated it's a multi-label classification: "in a **multi-label** classification task since classes ..." (emphasis mine). Maybe I don't understand your point of view. Please elaborate more.

Comment: in short: you can classify as multi-label (1 class), multi-class (1 label per class) or both. you response implies its 3d case but OP comment implies its 1st.. that what my comment was about.

Comment: @BoppityBop I think you are making it too complicated. By mutli-label classification we are referring to the problem where a sample may have zero, one or multiple labels (i.e. also "classes" in this context) assigned to it. For example, a task where there might be both "dog" and "cat" in an image, so the model should predict both "dog" and "cat". If there is only "dog" then it should predict only "dog".  This is also clearly stated in OP comment: "There are 18 labels, not classes, in the sense that every image has multi labels". There is actually no distinction between "label" and "class".

Comment: that was my point precisely. there is huge distinction between label and class

Comment: @BoppityBop It depends on how you want to define them. In the example of an image with both "dog" and "cat", you can say "both dog and cat **classes** are present in this sample" or you can say "this sample may be **labeled** with both dog and cat". So, the distinction does not tell us much; rather the **definition of the [classification] task** is important. You can choose to refer to "multi-label classification" as "mutli-class classification", and to "multi-class classification" as simply "classification". The definition matters. Though, I have used the common definition in my answer.