# Picking the right metric for a model ending with TimeDistributed layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to train a model for a NER task, with the model below. I am a bit confused about the right metrics to use here, I was expecting to use a classic CategoricalCrossentropy, but:

- the model evaluates the accuracy to zero when training and testing
- however when calculating the accuracy manually it's definitely not zero

I am not familiar with the TimeDistributed layer and I think the issue might be coming from here...
The shape of the output of the TD layer and the shape of my targets are the same

What am I am missing?

See below my code:

```
def init_model():
    input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(SEQ_LEN,),dtype='int32')
    attention_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(SEQ_LEN,),dtype='int32')
    
    x = backbone({'input_ids':input_ids,
                 'attention_mask':attention_mask})[0]

    backbone.trainable = False
    
    x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = 512,
                                                           activation = 'tanh',
                                                           #recurrent_dropout=.2,
                                                           dropout=.2,
                                                           return_sequences=True))(x)
    #x = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(x)
    x_res = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = 512,
                                                           activation = 'tanh',
                                                           #recurrent_dropout=.2,
                                                           dropout=.2,
                                                           return_sequences=True))(x)
    
    x = tf.keras.layers.add([x,x_res])
    output = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16,activation = 'softmax'))(x)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs={'input_ids':input_ids,
                                          'attention_mask':attention_mask},outputs=output)
    
    
    return model
```

and the compiling:

```
loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(name='categorical_crossentropy')
metric = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(name='accuracy')
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

model.compile(optimizer=opt,loss=loss,metrics=[metric])
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of the model's output? Time distributed layer preserves the temporal dimension so it seems like the output is of shape (Batch_size , SEQ_LEN, 16). Is this what you expect?

Comment: @xro7 the shape of the model output is (Batch_size , SEQ_LEN, 16), which is what I expected

Comment: So your labels have the same shape, right? Also, the problem you are dealing with is multilabel? If so maybe accuracy is not the appropriate metric to calculate performance. check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874485/multi-label-classification-keras-metrics

Comment: @xro7 that was right I should have used tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='accuracy') as pointed out in the question you linked. Thanks !

Comment: So binary accuracy was the default even though you have categorical_crossentropy as the loss metric?

Comment: @xro7 yes correct ; if you look back at the code I used I instantiated keras.metrics.Accuracy instead of keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy

Comment: Oh, I see! Let me submit an answer in case anyone stumbles upon this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that [tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Accuracy) is the same as binary accuracy.

In your case, you are dealing with a multiclass problem with categorical cross-entropy as the objective function. To properly calculate the accuracy use [tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/CategoricalAccuracy).

Another related answer to the issue is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53882065/3923800)